# Integrating $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to calculate

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$$

But I am unsure how to interpret the integral, does this mean integrating the function along any path starting at $0$ and ending at $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have remarked the complex integral 
$$\int_0^1{dz\over 1+z^2}$$
is not well defined unless you specify the intended path of integration. If this path is just the segment $$\sigma:\quad t\mapsto t\in{\mathbb C}\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)$$ then of course
$$\int_\sigma{dz\over 1+z^2}=\int_0^1{dt\over 1+t^2}={\pi\over 4}\ .$$
If, however, $\gamma$ is some arbitrary path beginning at $0$ and ending at $1\in{\mathbb C}$, then we can argue as follows: The path (chain) $\delta:=\gamma-\sigma$ is closed. If $\delta$ avoids the points $\pm i$, which we shall assume here, then by the general residue theorem we have
$$\int_\delta{dz\over 1+z^2}=2\pi i\bigl(n(\delta, i)\>{\rm res}(f,i) - n(\delta, -i)\>{\rm res}(f,-i)\bigr)\ .$$

The function
$$f(z):={1\over 1+z^2}={1\over (z-i)(z+i)}$$
has residues $\pm{1\over2i}$ at $\pm i$. It follows that
$$\int_\delta{dz\over 1+z^2}=\pi\bigl(n(\delta, i) - n(\delta, -i)\bigr)\ ,$$
so that we finally obtain
$$\int_\gamma{dz\over 1+z^2}=\int_\sigma{dz\over 1+z^2}+\int_\delta{dz\over 1+z^2}={\pi\over 4}+
\pi\bigl(n(\delta, i) - n(\delta, -i)\bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

This notation should be avoided. The most reasonable interpretation is the one you give, but in this particular case, the value of the integral is not independent of the chosen path.

Taking a path that winds around $z=i$ or $z=-i$ may result in a different value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm wondering though, how does one calculate the integral in that case?

Comment: You can't. Well you can express the integral in terms of the winding numbers of the curve with respect to $\pm i$. (If the curve passes through one of the poles, it's even worse.) In practice, I suspect the one who wrote down the integral meant integration along the line segment form $0$ to $1$, but it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: The person who wrote that did say along any path, and implied that there will be different values. I take that it doesn't depend on the curve when the curve doesn't pass through $\pm i$? Is it because it can be expressed as $pdx+qdy$?

Comment: W@user284954 no. If the curve wraps once around $z=i$, for example, we will pick up the (non-zero) residue at the pole. The problem is that you can define $\arctan z$ as holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ \pm i \}$.

Comment: I see, so we can use that to say that the integral is independent of endpoints when $\pm i \not \in \Omega$ because $\arctan z$ has this function as a derivative?

Comment: @user284954 Sorry, there was a **not** missing above: you can **not** define $\arctan z$ as a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\pm i\}$.

Answer (score 0):

it means
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz$$
and we can remember that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Um... I mean in the complex plane, which has more paths that can be considered.

Comment: ah then it's almost the same except you find a suitible path :) the path should not matter if it's differentiable.

Comment: It's more complicated than that since the integrand has poles at $\pm i$.

Comment: Yes, a closed curve integral will lead to the integral having the value of the poles (or whatever they are called in english) inside the curves region. I know :) But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The curve in question can't be closed (going from $0$ to $1$), but may still enclose one or both singularities.

Comment: It may but closing a curve can yield the desired result with some fancy manipulation